# can't turn on docker-compose with FastAPI "exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to run docker-compose with fastApi app, however I'm getting error

```
Cannot start service producer: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "uvicorn": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

my Dockerfiles looks like that

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
WORKDIR /code/producer
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY *.py /code/producer
CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `requirements.txt` file look like? Did you make sure to put `uvicorn` in there?

Comment: yes, it is in requirements

Comment: did oy try something like ```CMD ["pipenv", "run", "uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]``` ?